# Default Policies applied after QR provisioning - Unable to install apps

Tags: android, device-owner

I'm trying to provision my 7.0 device through QR provisioning. The provisioning was done successfully but default policies have been applied and i'm not unable to change it. These policies are configurable when i provision my device through adb provisioning.

For example i'm unable to install apps through playstore, sideload apps, do a factory reset etc.

Is there anything else i should be adding in my QR code provisioning data ?

Right now this is what i'm using:

{ "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "in.appslab.kardamom/in.appslab.kardamom.AdminReceiver", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM": "cheksumcode", "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION":"download location","android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED":true,"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_SKIP_ENCRYPTION":true,"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_ADMIN_EXTRAS_BUNDLE":{"company_key":"companykey" } }

Comment: Hey! You should be able to control the policies from your Device Policy Controller app. But it might be easier to not build a Device Policy Controller at all and instead use the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) to control the policies.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

The only mandatory fields to be included in Ndef Message are:
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION
EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM

You seem to be missing the first one.

Comment: Unfortunately even that doesn't work. I guess 'll have to use Android Management API